# Is there a way in pandas to aggregate one column as mean, and another as count?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, aggregate-functions

I cannot find solutions to that anywhere. What I am trying to achieve is: **dataframe** grouped by **'Machine'** column, next would be average column **'datetime'** and last one as a count of **'Barcode'**.

**Not working attempt:**

```
 result = df.groupby('Machine')['datetime'].aggregate('mean')['Barcode'].aggregate('count')
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8HiV.png  **<-- dateFrame before** operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.groupby(['Machine']).agg({'datetime':'mean', 'Barcode': 'count'})
```